# Python - Pass Arguments to Different Methods from Argparse

Tags: python, dynamic, methods, arguments, argparse

I'm writing a relatively simple Python script which supports a couple of different commands. The different commands support different options and I want to be able to pass the options parsed by argparse to the correct method for the specified command.

The usage string looks like so:

```
usage: script.py [-h]

            {a, b, c}
            ...
script.py: error: too few arguments
```

I can easily call the appropriate method:

```
def a():
    ...

def b():
    ...

def c():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.set_defaults(method = a)
    ...

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    arguments.method()
```

However, I have to pass arguments to these methods and they all accept different sets of arguments.

Currently, I just pass the `Namespace` object returned by argparse, like so:

```
 def a(arguments):
     arg1 = getattr(arguments, 'arg1', None)
     ...
```

This seems a little awkward, and makes the methods a little harder to reuse as I have to pass arguments as a `dict` or namespace rather than as usual parameters.

I would like someway of defining the methods with parameters (as you would a normal function) and still be able to call them dynamically while passing  appropriate parameters. Like so:

```
def a(arg1, arg2):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.set_defaults(method = a)
    ...

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    arguments.method() # <<<< Arguments passed here somehow
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found quite a nice solution:

```
import argparse

def a(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print arg1
    print arg2

if __name__ == "__main__":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.set_defaults(method = a)
        parser.add_argument('arg1', type = str)
        parser.add_argument('arg2', type = str)

        arguments = parser.parse_args()
        arguments.method(**vars(arguments))
```

Of course there's a minor problem if the arguments of the method clash with the  names of the arguments argparse uses, though I think this is preferable to passing the Namespace object around and using `getattr`.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to achieve the functionality that sub-commands provide:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: I'm using subparsers, what I'm trying to avoid is having the methods they call take an 'argument' argument which is supposed to be the Namespace instance returned from argparse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how practical this is, but by using [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) you can leave out the extraneous **kwargs parameter on your functions, like so:

```
import argparse
import inspect


def sleep(seconds=0):
    print "sleeping", seconds, "seconds"

def foo(a, b=2, **kwargs):
    print "a=",a
    print "b=",b
    print "kwargs=",kwargs

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommand")

parser_sleep = subparsers.add_parser('sleep')
parser_sleep.add_argument("seconds", type=int, default=0)
parser_sleep.set_defaults(func=sleep)

parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
parser_foo.add_argument("-a", type=int, default=101)
parser_foo.add_argument("-b", type=int, default=201)
parser_foo.add_argument("--wacky", default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)

args = parser.parse_args()

arg_spec = inspect.getargspec(args.func)
if arg_spec.keywords:
    ## convert args to a dictionary
    args_for_func = vars(args)
else:
    ## get a subset of the dictionary containing just the arguments of func
    args_for_func = {k:getattr(args, k) for k in arg_spec.args}

args.func(**args_for_func)
```

Examples:

```
$ python test.py sleep 23
sleeping 23 seconds

$ python test.py foo -a 333 -b 444
a= 333
b= 444
kwargs= {'func': <function foo at 0x10993dd70>}

$ python test.py foo -a 333 -b 444 --wacky "this is wacky"
a= 333
b= 444
kwargs= {'func': <function foo at 0x10a321d70>, 'wacky': 'this is wacky'}
```

Have fun!